# WatchKit how to specify main entry point in storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, watchkit, apple-watch

Unlike storyboards in the main app target, the one that comes with the WatchKit extension does not have a 'Main Entry Point' element that can be dragged to an Interface Controller.

How to set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. Need to check the 'Is Initial Controller' from within the Interface Controller's attributes inspector.